# PowerShell window border without Icon

Tags: forms, winforms, powershell, formborderstyle

I would like to create a windows form which does not contain an icon in the upper left corner. The problem is that I dont want to use the borderstyle "FixedToolWindow". I need to use the borderstyle "Fixed3D" but there is an icon by default. The following does not help:

> $window.Icon = $null

In this case he takes an default icon.

How can I completely get rid of the icon with the borderstyle "Fixed3D" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`ShowIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showicon(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `false`.

```
$f = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$f.ShowIcon=$False
$f.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That little thing saved my life :-)